# c++ download multiple files

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

I'm very new to c++ I've downloaded and compiled a few examples without issue.

Now I'm trying to download 10 files from a server and write each one to a different location/filename.

Looking at [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951161/downloading-multiple-files-with-libcurl-in-c) I've tried to use the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

void downloadFile(const char* url, const char* fname) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl){
        fp = fopen(fname, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

int main(void){
    downloadFile("http://servera.com/file.txt", "filename.txt");
    downloadFile("http://servera.com/file2.txt", "filename2.txt");
    downloadFile("http://serverb.com/file1.txt", "filename1b.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile it using `g++ test.cpp -o new` I get the following errors:

```
/tmp/cca1J32y.o: In function `downloadFile(char const*, char const*)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
test.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
test.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
test.cpp:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
test.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
test.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have googled to see if I can find what this means, but I haven't found anything I understand.

How do I get this to work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, that code is **not** C++, but C. Those are different languages, that aren't *really* compatible. There's very very many places on SO where that is discussed, so I won't go into detail here. You `#include <iostream>`, but don't use it anywhere.

Then, what you're seeing are linker errors, because you *use* the curl library, but don't tell the linker to use the library to resolve the function names to actual symbols that can be called.

try with `-lcurl`; again, this is C, and happens to be valid C++, too. You could compile this (if you remove the superfluous `#include <iostream>`) with `gcc` instead of `g++`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the curl library to link against. Most probably adding a `-lcurl` option to your compiler call will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You're correctly including the header for `libcurl`, but you also need to explicitly link against the dynamic library.  You probably need to compile as follows:

```
g++ test.cpp -o new -lcurl
```

where `-lcurl` tells the linker to link against the dynamic library called `libcurl.so` (on Unix systems).

Taking a look at the [Using libcurl page](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/using/), it actually provides a tool called `curl-config` that can help you with building the correct compiler command line.  On most Unix/Linux shells, you can use it as follows:

```
g++ $(curl-config --cflags --libs) test.cpp -o new
```

`curl-config --cflags --libs` will output the correct command-line options.  Placing that command in backticks or `$(...)` means that this output gets substituted onto your command line, effectively adding the command-line options to your command line.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks, you were faster than myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to link against the curl library. Add `-lcurl` to the end of your invocation, something like `g++ -o program program.cpp -lcurl`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the libcurl into your program. Use the -l argument to tell the linker which libraries you need. (Skip the "lib" of the library name)
`g++ test.cpp -o new -lcurl`