# Getting an empty CSV when downloading from URL in Cpp

Tags: c++, file, download, visual-studio-2017, libcurl

My goal is to get a CSV or XLS from a specific URL using Cpp.

When opening the following link

```
http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/userControls/GetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=01-01-2007&variation=PT
```

, can see in Browser tools

[image: Browser redirect]

a 302 redirect and the file being actually downloaded from the following URL

```
http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=02-01-2007&variation=PT
```

as shown in the next image (Request URL)

[image: Request URL]

**If I go to any of the two links manually, the a .xls file downloads just fine so we might as well use the one after redirection.**

---

I've decided to move on an use [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) with Visual Studio 2017 on my W10 machine. The recommended way to include libcurl in a Visual Studio 2017 project is to use [vcpkg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vcpkg?view=vs-2019) and that's what I used.

---

### 1. Install vcpkg

1. Open Git Bash, cd C:/Program Files/ and cloned [this repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg).

[image: Clone repo]

2. Open Command Prompt, cd C:/Program Files/vcpkg, run `bootstrap-vcpkg.bat`

[image: bootstrap-vcpkg.bat]

and after run `vcpkg integrate install`

[image: vcpkg integrate install]

---

### 2. Install libcurl

1. Run `vcpkg install curl`

[image: vcpkg install curl]

---

### 3. Create a new project

1. Simply create Visual C++ > Windows Desktop > Windows Console Application

[image: Windows Console Application]

to be able to use `#include <curl/curl.h>` right away

[image: use #include <curl/curl.h>]

---

### 4. Current Result

Then, inspired in the following answers

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6951203/9415908
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1636415/9415908

And using the following code

```
#include "pch.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

void downloadFile(const char* url, const char* fname) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(fname, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

int main(void) {

    downloadFile("http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=01-01-2007&variation=PT", "C:\\Users\\molecoder\\Desktop\\test.csv");

}
```

I can see a test.csv in the desired folder but it's an empty file.

[image: empty CSV]

Comment: Try adding quotes around the URL.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat currently using `std::string url = date.strftime("http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=%d-%m-%Y&variation=PT");`. Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: No, I'm saying `start` probably needs additional quotes around the URL. `std::string op = "start \"" + url + "\"";`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that solved the problem of the 'P' and 'variation' not being recognized yet it didn't download the file.

Comment: Why you do this in C++ and not C#/.Net?

Comment: @i486 i have used before Cpp to download from other sources and thought doing so would be another good opportunity to develop in the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once going to that specific URL, a .xls file downloads. I don't mind getting a XLS instead of a CSV and so changing it to I was able to get the file as expected.

```
downloadFile("http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=01-01-2007&variation=PT", "C:\\Users\\molecoder\\Desktop\\test.xls");
```

[image: It works]

This is the final code

```
#include "pch.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

void downloadFile(const char* url, const char* fname) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(fname, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

int main(void) {

    downloadFile("http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=01-01-2007&variation=PT", "C:\\Users\\molecoder\\Desktop\\test.xls");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how your shell works.

Note: When you use `system()` it is the shell that executes the command.

Your command:

> http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=01-01-2007&variation=PT

Your shell is treating the "&" character as the "and" operator. Execute the left and right side of the "and" as commands. So it is treating the above as three commands:

> http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG
> P=01-01-2007
> variation=PT

It fails on the second command `P=01-01-2007`

To fix this you may want to quote the string.

> "http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=01-01-2007&variation=PT"

```
 op.insert(0, 1, '"');
 op.append(1, '"');
 system(op.c_str());
```

Comment: Just updated the question after feedback from @HolyBlackCat.

Comment: @molecoder You just executed the `start` command: https://ss64.com/nt/start.html Setting the title to the url you specified.

Comment: I've used it before to download from a location where a file resided (https://location.com/file.csv)

Comment: @molecoder Read the doc I linked. "Start" is a command that runs a command in a window. **Your have simply set the title and not run a command**. So you don't need "start" or set the title and use the url as the command for "start"

Comment: Just read the doc you shared and I'm not understanding yet what you're hinting at...