# Download XLS files in a Cpp loop

Tags: c++, file, for-loop, download, libcurl

Developing from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62850908/9415908), wanted to generalize the behavior so that would download files within a specific data range.

So, modified the code to look like this

```
#include "pch.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

void downloadFile(const char* url, const char* fname) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(fname, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

struct mytm : std::tm {        // inherit "tm" to extend it a little
    mytm(int year, int month, int day) : tm{}, current{} {
        tm_year = year - 1900;
        tm_mon = month - 1;
        tm_mday = day;
        tm_hour = 12;
        current = mktime(this);
    }

    void add_days(int days) {
        current += days * 60 * 60 * 24;
        std::memcpy(this, std::localtime(&current), sizeof(std::tm));
    }

    std::string strftime(const char* format) {
        std::string retval(128, ' '); // a suitable sized buffer
        std::size_t len = std::strftime(&retval[0], retval.size(), format, this);

        retval.resize(len);
        return retval;
    }

    std::time_t current;
};

int main(void) {

    mytm date(2007, 1, 1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        Sleep(1000);
        std::string url =
            date.strftime("http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=%d-%m-%Y&variation=PT");

        std::string file_location =
            date.strftime("C:/Users/molecoder/Desktop/file_%d_%m_%Y.xls");

        // Pass std::string to a function that needs const char* - https://stackoverflow.com/a/347959/5675325
        const char * url_final = url.c_str();
        const char * file_location_final = file_location.c_str();

        downloadFile(url_final, file_location_final);
    }
}
```

While this downloads the a XLS file with the right name and data (so it's requesting correctly the URL)

[image: XLS works fine]

it does only so for the initial date - the day, month and year are not changing.

Comment: Why so complicated? Just `wget -c "http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=1-"{1..12}"-"{2019,2020}"&variation=PT"` would be enough

Comment: I'm exploring different ways to do it @sehe (also one with Python). Tested also with wget - https://stackoverflow.com/q/62871637/9415908

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign to `date` only once:

```
mytm date(2007, 1, 1);
```

And never modify that. So of course it doesn't change.

Update `date` before you format the new filename.

Comment: How can that be updated to increase the date gradually?

Comment: In anywhich way you want? You already know how to set one, so perhaps just make an array, or some loops http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fd76e8163c2bbd5 (maybe even use that adddays function)

Comment: FWIW I can't download a single one of these, but I notice that none of `stream` or `ptr` are being checked in `write_data`.

Comment: It wasn't that easy to understand in this specific case as even the title of the answer was "Download XLS files in a Cpp loop". The files weren't being downloaded though.

Answer (score 1):

As [sehe says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62867494/9415908), the problem is the date not being modified and so I needed to update `date`, like this

```
#include "pch.h"
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

void downloadFile(const char* url, const char* fname) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(fname, "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

struct mytm : std::tm {        // inherit "tm" to extend it a little
    mytm(int year, int month, int day) : tm{}, current{} {
        tm_year = year - 1900;
        tm_mon = month - 1;
        tm_mday = day;
        tm_hour = 12;
        current = mktime(this);
    }

    void add_days(int days) {
        current += days * 60 * 60 * 24;
        std::memcpy(this, std::localtime(&current), sizeof(std::tm));
    }

    std::string strftime(const char* format) {
        std::string retval(128, ' '); // a suitable sized buffer
        std::size_t len = std::strftime(&retval[0], retval.size(), format, this);

        retval.resize(len);
        return retval;
    }

    std::time_t current;
};

int main(void) {
    
    for (int year : {2018, 2019})
        for (int month : {1, 11})
            for (int day : {1, 31}) {
                std::cout << 
                    mytm(year, month, day)
                    .strftime("http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=%d-%m-%Y&variation=PT")
                    << std::endl;

                Sleep(1000);
                
                std::string url =
                    mytm(year, month, day).strftime("http://www.centrodeinformacao.ren.pt/_layouts/CI.GetExcel/SafeGetExcel.aspx?T=CRG&P=%d-%m-%Y&variation=PT");

                std::string file_location =
                    mytm(year, month, day).strftime("C:/Users/molecoder/Desktop/file_%d_%m_%Y.xls");

                // Pass std::string to a function that needs const char* - https://stackoverflow.com/a/347959/5675325
                const char * url_final = url.c_str();
                const char * file_location_final = file_location.c_str();

                downloadFile(url_final, file_location_final);
            }


}
```

Notice that some of the files won't have data and would get the following result

> Ocorreu um
> erro.REN_CRG_Total::pr_REN_CRG_SelectTotalByDate_Excel::Error occured.

[image: Hm...]